# Random number generation function not work

Tags: r, for-loop, random, functional-programming, numbers

The first function works well, generates random numbers:

```
n <-10
inv.f <- array(0, dim=c(n ,1))
for(i in 1:n){ 
    u <- runif(1,0,1) 
    gexp.cdf <- function(x,beta=5.5){ (1-exp(-beta*x))-u } 
    inv.f[i,] <-  uniroot(gexp.cdf, lower=0, upper=5,extendInt="yes")$root
}
inv.f
```

The second function did not work; it did not generate random numbers.

```
RN <- function(n){
    inv.f <- array(0, dim=c(n ,1))
    for(i in 1:n){ 
       u <- runif(1,0,1) 
       gexp.cdf <- function(x,beta=5.5){ (1-exp(-beta*x))-u } 
       inv.f[i,] <-  uniroot(gexp.cdf, lower=0, upper=5,extendInt="yes")$root
    }
}
RN(5)
```

Comment: you need to add a return statement as the last line of your function, e.g. `return(inv.f)` (this could also be done implicitly, by making that line just `inv.f`)

Comment: -Ben Bolker, thank you for your comments.But after adding it follow result obtained

Comment: RN(10) # NOT Work as I want 
         [,1]
 [1,] 6.32196
 [2,] 0.00000
 [3,] 0.00000
 [4,] 0.00000
 [5,] 0.00000
 [6,] 0.00000
 [7,] 0.00000
 [8,] 0.00000
 [9,] 0.00000
[10,] 0.00000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that functions in R return the value of the *last* expression executed within the function. In your current version, this would be the last element evaluated in the loop. This solution (adding `return(inv.f)` as the last statement in the function) works for me:

```
RN <- function(n){
    inv.f <- array(0, dim=c(n ,1))
    for (i in 1:n){ 
       u <- runif(1,0,1) 
       gexp.cdf <- function(x,beta=5.5){ (1-exp(-beta*x))-u } 
       inv.f[i,] <-  uniroot(gexp.cdf, lower=0, upper=5,extendInt="yes")$root
    }
    return(inv.f)
}
```

Example:

```
set.seed(101)
RN(3)
##             [,1]
## [1,] 0.084651167
## [2,] 0.008147968
## [3,] 0.224888903
```